# using (-) dash in mysql table name

Tags: mysql

There is an error while i want to backup my database

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-01-000001' at line 1

SELECT * FROM temp_01-01-000001

Filename: F:\xampp\htdocs\erp_zaara\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Is there any way to solve this prob with the table name (temp_01-01-000001).

Comment: My general advice is: don't use table names that contain illegal characters (and thus require quoting). They are much more trouble then they are worth it. This is just another example.

Comment: Dash (-) it is not an illegal character, but it must be quoted with backticks (`). See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html and  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=461

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could edit line 132 of the file /system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_utility.php

From:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
```

To:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
```

Comment: tbh I think that Jhanvi’s comment would be the way to go on this; manually modifying drivers is problematic for many reasons.

Answer (score 68):

You have to add quotes as your table name contains number. I think the following query will work.

```
SELECT * FROM `temp_01-01-000001`
```

Comment: there is no manual query. its codeigniter dbutil for database backup

Comment: Thanks, finally find a way!