# How do I deal with SQL tablenames with hyphen (-) when writing raw queries? i.e project-users

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table called `project-users` and want to write a SQL query like `SELECT * FROM project-users` I get this error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"`. 
I cannot change the table name at this point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using (-) dash in mysql table name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670394/using-dash-in-mysql-table-name)

Comment: You need to escape the name.  Postgres uses double quotes.  You can review the documentation on this:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html.

Comment: Double quoting invalid names is the Standard SQL approach, but this also results in case_sensitive object names, e.g. "a" and "A" are different tables. The basic recommendation is to avoid any names where quoting is needed, e.g. `project_users` instead of `"project users"` or `"project-users"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html, you should use double quotes.

In your case, for PostgreSQL the query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM "project-users";
```

It is good practice to avoid the use of characters that need escaping or that contain spaces in identifiers.